# How can I kill or stop cassandra immediately on os x?

Tags: java, macos, cassandra

After install java and Cassandra, java is running on more than 2GB of my mac memory and at least half percent of CPU for all time. I tried `ps -ax | grep cassandra` and `kill pid` or `ps -ax | grep java` but didn't work and java still running on memory! what is the solution? how can I stop Cassandra or java to stop battery draining when I don't use them?

I am not sure about java is draining my battery but I guess It's will!

[image]

Comment: Kill all the java processes

Comment: I kill java process but It's starting again.

Comment: Are there any services auto-starting?

Comment: Use a pkill otherwise, something like is the syntax pkill -f 'java'

Comment: pkill -f 'java' does not affect